# How to handle <Element id="someValue">Hello World</Element> in jaxb dynamically?

Tags: xml, jaxb, java-8

Hello World

How to generate in **jaxb** dynamically certain cases where we need to create a element object to set Attribute. But dont need sub-elements.

Answer (score 0):

We can handle this case using `@XmlValue` over a variable under Element class like :

```
public class Element {

  @XmlAttribute(name="id")
  private String id;

  @XmlValue
  private String name;

  /* getters & setters */
}
```